# Styling a Razor HTML Helper in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a situation where I call a variable to show if a user is logged in:

```
@{
var loggedInUser = User.Identity.GetUserName();
}
```

Then later on I call the variable

```
<p> You are logged in as: @loggedInUser @Html.ActionLink("(Log Out)", "LogOut", "Account")      </p>
```

How would I go about styling the @loggedInUser?  I can't find a solution for the life of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it inside another element, for example

```
<p> You are logged in as: <span id="user">@loggedInUser</span> @Html.ActionLink(...
```

Then style the element

```
#user {
  color:red;
}
```